# Applying impulse on a SpriteKit node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a Sprite Kit Game, which I have a node named hero who dodges approaching villains. I have an issue with `applyImpulse` for a jump action and, in this case, the hero can jump repeatedly and fly instead of dodging the villains. I'm used a boolean variable to change the status with a timer value to jump only once in 3 seconds but that is not working. Here is my code

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if isGameOver == true {
        self.restart()
    }

    if isstarted {
        self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("jump.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
        for touch: AnyObject in touches{
            if jumpon == false {  //hero has not jumped
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                heroAction()
                jumpon = true   //hero jumped
            }
        }

    } else { 
        isstarted = true
        hero.stop()
        hero.armMove()
        hero.rightLegMove()
        hero.leftLegMove()
        treeMove()
        villanMove()
        let clickToStartLable = childNodeWithName("clickTostartLable")
        clickToStartLable?.removeFromParent()
        addGrass()
       // star.generateStarWithSpawnTime()
    }
}

func changeJump(){
    jumpon = false // hero has landed
}
```

and function update is called in every second and then `changeJump` must be called

```
 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if isstarted == true {
        let pointsLabel = childNodeWithName("pointsLabel") as MLpoints
        pointsLabel.increment()
    }

    if jumpon == true { // checked everyframe that hero jumped
        jumpingTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "changeJump", userInfo: nil, repeats: true) // changing jump status
    }
}
```

How should I update my code to make the hero jump only once in three seconds. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts...

1. I suggest you use an `SKAction` or two instead of an `NSTimer` in Sprite Kit games. `SKAction`s pause/resume appropriately when you pause/resume the scene and/or view
2. The `update` method is called ~60 times a second not every second
3. Checking the status of a jump in `update` is not need
4. Alternatively, you can check if the hero is on the ground before starting another jump sequence instead of using a timer. The game may frustrate the user if the hero is on the ground (and ready to jump) but the timer is still counting down

and some code...

```
if (!jumping) {
    jumping = true
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
    let leap = SKAction.runBlock({
        // Play sound and apply impulse to hero
        self.jump()
    })
    let action = SKAction.group([leap, wait])
    runAction(action) {
        // This runs only after the action has completed
        self.jumping = false
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm assuming that each jump may last 2 or 3 seconds,if this didn't work well then thats my choice ,thanks!